# Nested Bootstrap layout with padding

Tags: html, layout, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create a nested Bootstrap layout with padding in one of the sections?

An illustration is below. If I wrap `#main-container` in a Bootstrap div with `.span12`, it works. But that means that `#main-content` is now 40px thinner than the `.span12` width, which means I can't use the Boostrap grid inside of it. (For instance, it'd be great to make `#left-column` a `.span9` and `#right-column` a `.span3`, but I can't.)

Is there a better way to create this layout?

[image: Layout illustration]

Comment: Is that a fluid or fixed layout?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it really depends on what you want to achieve with the padding.

For instance, if you want a background in the space provided by the padding, you most certainly need an actual padding. **But** if on the other hand you just want some spacing, you should be able to stick to the original grid (giving margins to the `.span` children instead of their container).

Based on your layout, the fluid solution is obviously more adaptable and easier to implement.

Takes advantage of the fluid grid inside the padded element : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/u6SPr/embedded/result/)

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12" id="header">#header</div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12" id="main-content">#main-content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span9" id="left-column">#left-column</div>
            <div class="span3" id="right-column">#right-column</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update** Added a more explicit border and background : [Border demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/u6SPr/1/embedded/result/)

```css
#main-container {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    background: yellow;
}
#main-container > .row-fluid { background: white; }
```

Comment: Yes, the goal is to add a border and background. Do you have any thoughts on how to make that work?

Comment: @JosephMornin The markup already supports that. See my edit for an example.